# Copy/pasting layer's label style only between layers using QGIS GUI

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, shortcuts

**Is it possible in the QGIS GUI to copy/paste a layer's *label style properties only* between layers?**

In QGIS (2.18.1, win7), while it is possible to copy a layer's entire style (*symbology + label style properties*) and then paste it to another layer (assuming geometry type is the same), it doesn't seem possible to *only* copy the layer's *label style properties* to then paste it to another layer (whether of the same geometry type or irrespective thereof).

According to my shortcut configurations, copying and pasting an entire style between layers is achieved by the very simple and handy: `SHIFT-C` --- `SHIFT-V`

Is there currently, or a way to configure, a function (that could similarly be turned into a QGIS GUI shortcut) to just copy/paste a layers' *label style properties only* (or conversely only the layers symbol style)?

Comment: The short answer is no not at the moment as a core feature.  It will copy the whole style XML block to the clipboard

Comment: Having said that, bit of a hack but copy to clipboard, strip out everything except label, copy and paste back. Should work.

Comment: Thanks @NathanW for considering this. I copied the XML block to the clipboard, opened it up in a microsoft Notepad, and thought wow, what the hell is all that about. I found some bits seemingly about labelling but it wasn't clear to me how to just remove the styling parts to leave the labelling parts in order to paste them back ...... if anyone can assist making the next step understandable for the laity such as me that would be grand!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality (and so much more like it) has now been implemented in QGIS 3.4.

For the basic instructions see:
http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.4-LTR/#partial-qml-export-import

(though this is from the temporary change-log)

Just right hand click on a layer in the layers panel, go down to "Styles", then "Copy Style", choose which part of the layer you want to copy, then right hand click on the one you want to paste it to, click "Styles", "Paste Style", and click the ones you want to paste.

[image: http://changelog.qgis.org/media/images/entries/93836361649c4b182b46e143014d7f30be674187.png]