# QGIS copy style between different geometries failed

Tags: qgis, style, style-manager

I would like to know how to manage styling between different layer geometries, assuming that the data attribute columns remain the same.

The hint explained here:

[Copy/pasting layer's label style only between layers using QGIS GUI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220837/copy-pasting-layers-label-style-only-between-layers-using-qgis-gui)

works only for the same geometry.

When I tried to do it between various geometries I had an error:

**Cannot paste style: Cannot apply a style with symbology to layer with a different geometry type**

which is a bug explained here:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12303

[image]

Is there any solution for copying the style between layers in different geometry in QGIS assuming, that the naming of data attribute tables is the same?

Comment: One link deals with label styles, another one with geometry styles. Which styles would you like to copy?

Comment: I make a test and it is possible to copy-paste label styles between point and polygon layers. I do not know how pasting geometry styles could work, for example if polygon has a fill color, what would it paint on line or point layers? Or what effect would point symbols have on lines and polygons?

Comment: It wasn't possible in my case. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me with QGIS 3.18

Create two test layers with similarly named attribute for labels

[image]

Configure labels for one layer and copy styles

[image]

Paste styles to another layer

[image]

Labels appear

[image]